# git@gitee.com: Permission denied (publickey), not a common problem, to be solved

Tags: git, ssh

About publickey: I configured it a year ago and it works fine!

[image]

However, I can't `push` to any **gitee** repositories from yesterday.

> Permission denied (publickey)

But it works well in **github**?! (I'm sure I'm using the same publickey and it was added before)

[image]

After running `$ ssh -Tvvv git@gitee.com` , I got the following message:

[image]

```sh
# other infos
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/57715/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/57715/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/57715/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/57715/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/57715/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/57715/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/57715/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/57715/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/57715/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/57715/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/57715/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/57715/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@gitee.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I've been searching for that answer all day, could somebody help to solve the tough problem?

I would appreciate it very much!

Comment: Probably gitee revoked certain RSA keys. You need to ask the gitee people, though.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code and output, but the actual text instead.

Comment: @Nils Werner Well, I will pay attention to it!

Comment: @torek Yeah! You're right, I found a passage about "Why RSA-SHA1 doesn't work in gitee". It shows me the answer correctly!

Comment: @Nils Werner The reason why I post screenshots of code is when I use actual text instead, the code was flagged as suspected spam~

Comment: If that's the case, then you'll have to wait until somebody unflags your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if this was working before, that would mean you are sharing one SSH key between multiple destinations, which is not a good practice.

As explained in "[Generate/add SSH public key](https://gitee.com/help/articles/4181)", I would generate a new key dedicated for gitee access/authentication

```
cd %USERPROFILE%\.ssh
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C  "xxxxx@xxxxx.com"  -P "" -f gitee
```

Note the recommended protocol here: ed25519. `rsa` might no longer be allowed.

> Copy the generated ssh key, and add the generated public key to the warehouse via "Management" -> "Deployment Public Key Management" -> "Add Deployment Public Key" on the warehouse homepage .
>
> [image: https://images.gitee.com/uploads/images/2018/0814/233212_29a62378_551147.png]

Then create a `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` file, with in it:

```
Host gitee.com 
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa 
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Test this is working with `ssh -T git@gitee.com`

Finally, in the root folder of your local repository:

```
git remote set-url origin giteee:<me>/<myProject>
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work..  

I finally solved it thanks to your answer. It inspired me. 

Just to create a `config` file in `~/.ssh/` directory like what you said. But the content is a litter different. 
`Host gitee.com  HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa` 
Thanks a lot! guy!
 
I edit it, and you can have a see~

Comment: This is my first time asking questions. I'm new here and earned 15 reputation just now. And I give u a upvote and accept it at the moment. I'm still figuring out how to use this community. Thanks~

Comment: @Wu-Yikun You got it. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you tried `ed25519` the first time, maybe add

```
Host gitee.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

to ~/.ssh/config should work.